# Can't connect dell 1600n scanner on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, scanner, multi-function-printer

I have a dell 1600n multifunction printer with scanner. Printing is no problem but i cant connect the scanner.

I followed the instruction on [SANE - Installing a scanner that isn't auto-detected](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SANE%20-%20Installing%20a%20scanner%20that%20isn't%20auto-detected).

When i execute 'sane-find-scanner' im getting error:

```
could not open USB device 0x413c/0x5220 at 001:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

The output from ls /etc/sane.d/ is:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Mai  5 09:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 136 root root 12288 Mai  4 22:20 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    25 Sep 18  2015 abaton.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    14 Sep 18  2015 agfafocus.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    24 Sep 18  2015 apple.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    26 Sep 18  2015 artec.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4140 Sep 18  2015 artec_eplus48u.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   548 Sep 18  2015 avision.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    29 Sep 18  2015 bh.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   193 Sep 18  2015 canon630u.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    26 Sep 18  2015 canon.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3885 Sep 18  2015 canon_dr.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1160 Sep 18  2015 canon_pp.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   509 Sep 18  2015 cardscan.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   754 Sep 18  2015 coolscan2.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   754 Sep 18  2015 coolscan3.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    34 Sep 18  2015 coolscan.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   984 Sep 18  2015 dc210.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   984 Sep 18  2015 dc240.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   704 Sep 18  2015 dc25.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   507 Mai  5 09:43 dell1600n_net.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1098 Mai  1 09:39 dll.conf
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 30 13:47 dll.d
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    12 Sep 18  2015 dmc.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2569 Sep 18  2015 epjitsu.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   376 Sep 18  2015 epson2.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   793 Sep 18  2015 epson.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   221 Sep 18  2015 epsonds.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2248 Sep 18  2015 fujitsu.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2008 Sep 18  2015 genesys.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   877 Jan 29  2014 geniusvp2.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1149 Sep 18  2015 gphoto2.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  7795 Sep 18  2015 gt68xx.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   396 Sep 18  2015 hp3900.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    76 Sep 18  2015 hp4200.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   238 Sep 18  2015 hp5400.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   497 Sep 18  2015 hp.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    22 Sep 18  2015 hpsj5s.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    24 Sep 18  2015 hs2p.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    38 Sep 18  2015 ibm.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2599 Sep 18  2015 kodakaio.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   367 Sep 18  2015 kodak.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   113 Sep 18  2015 leo.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   119 Sep 18  2015 lexmark.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   187 Sep 18  2015 ma1509.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1254 Sep 18  2015 magicolor.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   666 Sep 18  2015 matsushita.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   279 Sep 18  2015 microtek2.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   268 Sep 18  2015 microtek.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2125 Sep 18  2015 mustek.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3824 Sep 18  2015 mustek_pp.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   809 Sep 18  2015 mustek_usb.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    13 Sep 18  2015 nec.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   573 Sep 18  2015 net.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   365 Sep 18  2015 p5.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    75 Sep 18  2015 pie.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   492 Sep 18  2015 pixma.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4142 Sep 18  2015 plustek.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   943 Sep 18  2015 plustek_pp.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   391 Sep 18  2015 qcam.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    29 Sep 18  2015 ricoh.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   183 Sep 18  2015 rts8891.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    13 Sep 18  2015 s9036.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1052 Sep 18  2015 saned.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    48 Sep 18  2015 sceptre.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1464 Sep 18  2015 sharp.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   115 Sep 18  2015 sm3840.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2239 Sep 18  2015 snapscan.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    10 Sep 18  2015 sp15c.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2224 Sep 18  2015 st400.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   178 Sep 18  2015 stv680.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    28 Sep 18  2015 tamarack.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   355 Sep 18  2015 teco1.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   636 Sep 18  2015 teco2.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   217 Sep 18  2015 teco3.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1807 Sep 18  2015 test.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1495 Sep 18  2015 u12.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   386 Sep 18  2015 umax1220u.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3094 Sep 18  2015 umax.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1684 Sep 18  2015 umax_pp.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3424 Sep 18  2015 xerox_mfp.conf
```

And this is the result of command ls -al /dev/bus/usb/001:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     80 Mai  5 17:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root    300 Mai  5 09:38 ..
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189, 0 Mai  5 17:57 001
crw-rw-r--  1 root lp   189, 2 Mai  5 17:57 003
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls /etc/sane.d/ ? 
`

Comment: Is your user part of the `scanner` group?

Comment: Also, please provide the output of `ls -al /dev/bus/usb/001`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add yourself to the `lp` group and log out/in.

```
gpasswd -a your_user lp
```

Because it's a multifunction printer, it's not the `scanner` group.

Do note however, that [this scanner is not supported over USB](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-DELL)!

Comment: I've added my user first to the lp group, this did not help. Than i added saned to the lp group but this did not help either.

Comment: After adding yourself to the `lp` group, you should be able to run `sane-find-scanner`. If not, please try again as root, to verify it’s working at all.

Comment: executing `sane-find-scanner` the scanner is found. But it seems that this scanner is not supported over usb.